# C++ reserved class name alias similar to __super?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**Is there any alias, even if MSVC specific, that acts as the name of the current class?** So if I have:

```
struct a_class {
    a_class *parent = nullptr;
};
```

And later decide to rename the class, at least its internal self references will no longer need to be renamed. Like:

```
struct a_class {
    __class *parent = nullptr; // imaginary class name alias
};
```

There's already `__super` to refer to inherited classes. But I don't think there's a reserved name to alias the current class name. Is there?

**PS**: *I know it can be done with a `typedef class_name Self_t`. And then use `Self_t` all over but I was wondering if there's a keyword I'm missing.*

Comment: @BartoszKP No Macros, thanks. :)

Comment: decltype of this would be enough?

Comment: @paulm Does not compile in MSVC.

Comment: @paulm: Only inside a (non-static) member function. Elsewhere in the class definition, there is no `this`.